# Changing things within Settings

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am newbie in windows phone 8 development, but have been programming for years. I have the 2012 SDK installed and have two buttons, "On" and "Off" on a new Phone App.

I want to access the "Settings" -> "Internet Sharing" and turn it on or off with single tap to a button or better yet, toggle on/off with a a single button based on current status.

I have spent hours on the msdn site going over hundreds of code examples, but have not found anything yet that showed access to the items within "Settings."

Could someone please give me some example (C#) code snippets for the Event

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

and/or

```
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

Is there also a Reserved Word Reference for win8 phone C# and/or XAML somewhere that I can download. I am guessing it is on the msdn website, but so far it is alluding me very well.

Comment: AFAIK, most of the phone settings are not changeable with code from apps.  You can take the user to the settings screen, but they have to make the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot turn on/off internet sharing from your app, there is no way to do it with the current SDK.

Comment: Thanks, OK, stuck with it.